# How can I include the number of relationships in a household in exported data for that household

Tags: contacts

I need to mail multiple copies of our Client and Family Newsletter to households shared by individual clients.

How can I access the 'number of relationships' for each household (visible in the top ribbon), so that I could include that number in the info I give to the mail house, so that they can put the right number of copies in the envelope for each household?

Or is there a better way to achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pete's answer is the only solution I can think of that doesn't require coding, but it's only an option for Drupal users.

If you're on Joomla/Wordpress, you'll need to code a solution, or hire someone to do so.  Create a custom field on the contact "number of relationships".  Create an extension with `civix` and use `hook_civicrm_post` on any relationship being created/updated/deleted; use an API call to `getcount` for relationships, and populate the number of relationships to your custom field.

If you know SQL but not PHP, an easier solution is to set up a cron job to fill in the custom field with a SQL statement that runs over the whole database.  I'm not sure if you can use an UPDATE statement with a GROUP BY though - so you might need to use a subselect, which is expensive.

The other SQL-centric option is to create a trigger to handle this.  You can be quick and dirty and drop it right into the database, or you can wrap it in a CiviCRM extension.  If you go the latter route, consider coding it into the "Summary Fields" extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I don't have a solution in CiviCRM directly. if you are using Drupal, then I would expect that you can make a View that uses Aggregation that should give you the count of relationshipss along with address etc which you could then print out as Mailing Labels either via a PDF plugin for Views, or view an external 'mail merge' solution.